# How to get browser to ignore password fields on a "change my password" form?

Tags: html, spring, jsp, web, authentication

I have a web app (JSP, Spring, Tomcat) and after the user is logged in, they can click a "Change Password" link which prompts them with a simple form with "Password" and "Confirm Password" fields.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">New Password:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Confirm New Password:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Works fine, except the browser thinks this is a login form and prompts the user if they want to save the password in the browser.

My understanding is `autocomplete="off"` was intended to prevent the prompting, but modern browsers ignore that field.

Alternately, is there some way to use `type="text"` and still have the characters displayed as masked bullet characters?

Answer (score 0):

The valid options for `autocomplete` are `on` and `off`, not `true/false.`

Comment: Thanks -- I corrected it in my question.  My understanding, though, is that modern browsers will ignore that field.  Is that not true?

Comment: Your post contains `autocomplete="no"` instead of `autocomplete="on"`, is it a typo in your post? Correct, password managers may choose to ignore the setting. From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values):


    In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not prevent a
    password manager from asking the user if they would like to save username
    and password information, or from automatically filling in those values in a
    site's login form. See the autocomplete attribute and login fields.

Comment: Thanks.  Changed to "off".  Tested in Firefox and "off" is not preventing the browser from prompting to store password.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of Chrome the way you described does not work. Try this:

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="user-password">
```